# Utilizar dbcontexto para obtener DataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, net, core

Lo que quisiera saber es si hay forma de utilizar DbContext para obtener un datatable,esto para no utilizar un SqlConnection, es decir, me gustaría reutilizar ya la conexión existente.
Aquí una imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

finalmente lo que hize fue lo siguiente, si alguien tiene otra salida, por favor me la hace conocer.

```
            using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(_contextoFile.Database.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            var commando = new SqlCommand();
            commando.Connection = conexion;
            commando.CommandText = "Create Table #Suministro (idNroservicio int)";
            commando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            commando.Parameters.Clear();
            commandText = "Insert Into #Suministro (idNroservicio) Select Cast(s.idNroservicio as int) From @Suministro As s;";
            commando.CommandText = commandText;
            var parametros = new SqlParameter("@Suministro", dtExcel);
            parametros.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            parametros.TypeName = "dbo.SuministroTipoTabla";
            commando.Parameters.Add(parametros);
            commando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            commando.Parameters.Clear();
            commando.CommandText = "Exec NF_DocumentosColumna";
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(commando);
            da.Fill(dtFile);
        }
```